# check what image is set to image view each 500 ms

Tags: android

I am working on this small game where each 500 ms an image is set to the image view 
so what i want to check is when i click one of the arrow images(left,right,up,down) to check if it is equal to the random image ...if so then the score increases by 1.
here is my layout
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPxZB.png

and here is my code

> ```
>     package com.andreh.catchthatarrow;
>
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.animation.Animation;
> import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
> import android.widget.ImageView;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import java.util.Timer;
> import java.util.TimerTask;
>
> public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>     ImageView img_up;
>     ImageView img_down;
>     ImageView img_left;
>     ImageView img_right,imgRand;
>
>     private int time = 600;
>     private static int SCORE = 0;
>     private TextView score;
>     int pos = 0;
>
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
>         score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
>         img_up = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgUp);
>         img_down = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDown);
>         img_left = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLeft);
>         img_right = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgRight);
>         imgRand = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.changeable);
>
>         final int [] arrBuckets = {R.drawable.arrow_left,R.drawable.arrow_right,R.drawable.up,R.drawable.down};
>
>         Timer mTimer = new Timer();
>         mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void run() {
>
>                         pos = arrBuckets[(int) (Math.random() * arrBuckets.length)];
>
>                         imgRand.setImageResource(pos);
>
>                         if(time>10 || time<20) time=100;
>
>
>
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         },0,time);
>
>
>
>         img_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 if(pos==2){
>                     SCORE++;
>                     score.setText(SCORE+"");
>
>                 }
>
>
>             }
>         });
>
>         img_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 if(pos==3){
>                     SCORE++;
>                     score.setText(SCORE+"");
>
>                 }
>
>             }
>         });
>         img_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 if(pos==0){
>                     SCORE++;
>                     score.setText(SCORE+"");
>
>                 }
>
>
>             }
>         });
>        img_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 if(pos==1){
>                     SCORE++;
>                     score.setText(SCORE+"");
>
>                 }
>
>
>             }
>         });
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: what should i tell you, you're setting images yourself using a random function, instead of getting which image is in the imageview from ImageView class you can just keep that information in your fragment class and then increment the score accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the data in the index and you need the position so use this instead:

```
pos = Array.asList(arrayBuckets).indexOf((int) (Math.random() * arrBuckets.length));

img_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
         if(pos==2)
            {
        SCORE++; 
        score.setText(SCORE+""); 
        }

        });
```

Comment: @AndrehAbboud My plessure remember use another int called drawable for the image setImageResource